# Enable Dropdown Selection Using a Checkbox, Toggle Dependent Dropdown and DIV Visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, toggle, visibility

I have an interesting scenario involves using a checkbox to enable the a dropdown. Upon changing the status of the 1st dropdown, it should enables the 2nd dropdown. Once a selection is made in the 2nd dropdown, it toggles the visibility of 2 hidden DIVs.  Like the image below:

[image]

I have a prototype [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/Lesyh0jm/) that I've been working on but there are a few issues with the script, such as:

**1-** Despite the dropdowns contain the "**disabled**" attribute, which should be enabled only once the checkbox is checked, but it only works if you click the checkbox 2 times. Here's the script:

```
var $checkBox = $('#mondayTransfer'),
    $select = $('#mondayOptions');
$checkBox.on('change',function(e){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $select.removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
       $select.attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

**2-** The 2nd Selection dropdown should also be disabled; changes to the 1st Selection dropdown would enable it. Here's the script:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'mondayOptions' && $(this).val() == 'Default'){
            $('select').not(this).prop('disabled', true).val('Disabled');
        } else {
           $('select').not(this).removeProp('disabled');
           $('select option').removeProp('disabled');
           $('select').each(function(){
               var val = $(this).val();
                if(val != 'Default' || val != 'Disabled'){
                    $('select option[value="'+val+'"]').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

});

**3-** Once the checkbox is unchecked, all the dropdowns should be disabled.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored you code a little bit, you can test it [here](https://repl.it/@notundefined/stackoverflow-60404752)

```
let $checkBox = $('#mondayTransfer');

let divClasses = ['.ach', '.flash'];    
let selects = ['#mondayOptions', '#box_g2'];    

let setDisplayNone = function(className) {
  divClasses.forEach(function(className) {
    $(className).css("display", 'none');
  });
}

$checkBox.on('change',function(e){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#mondayOptions').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        // Disable both selects when mondayOptions is CHECKED
        $('select').attr('disabled','disabled');

        // Loop through each div you can select and set its display none
        setDisplayNone(divClasses)
        
        // Loop each select you have and then select the "selected" option
        selects.forEach(function(className) {
            $(className).val('selected');
        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // When mondayOption is changed enable the second drop-down
  $("#mondayOptions").change(function() {
    $("#box_g2").attr("disabled", false)
  });
  
  // When the second drop-down changes its value
  $("#box_g2").change(function() {
    // set display none to all toggleDiv
    setDisplayNone(divClasses)

    // fetch the value selected
    let className = $(this).val();

    // use jquery to select the div and set the display yo block
    $('.' + className).css('display', 'block')
  });
});
```

If you remove all the code from //Enable drop-down Selection section of your snippet you would get part of the behaviour that you wanted to.

Anyhow here is how it is working now:

When the checkbox is **CHECKED**:

1. Enable the first drop-down.

When the checkbox is ***IS NOT* CHECKED**:

1. Disabled both selects
2. Make all .divToggle not visible by using the setDisplayNone function
3. Reset the value of the selects to the default value("selected" in your case)

When you select a value on the second drop-down:

1. Make all .divToggle not visible by using the setDisplayNone function
2. fetch the value selected
3. use jquery to select the div and set the display yo block

Comment: I'm grateful for your help and the solution you offered!  If I could throw a curve ball, how would I be able to scale the solution by adding rows for Tuesday, Wednesday and so on through Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

### Check this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wth8mrLa/

Updated some of your scripts;

1) moved the scripts inside DOM ready

2) added select box2 variable `$select2 = $('#box_g2');`

3) when checkbox uncheck, disable both select boxes, reset null values and hide div

the rest scripts are the same.

#### JQUERY

```
//Toggle DIV Visibility Using the 2nd Dropdown Selection
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("select").change(function() {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if (optionValue) {
                $(".divToggle").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else {
                $(".divToggle").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();

    //Toggle 1st Selection Dropdown Once Checkbox is Checked
    var $checkBox = $('#mondayTransfer'),
        $select = $('#mondayOptions'),
        $select2 = $('#box_g2');

    $checkBox.on('change', function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $select.prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $select.val('').prop('disabled', true);
            $select2.val('').prop('disabled', true);
            $(".divToggle").hide();
        }
    });

    //Enable DropDown Selection
    $(function() {
        $('select').change(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'mondayOptions' && $(this).val() == 'Default') {
                $('select').not(this).prop('disabled', true).val('Disabled');
            } else {
                $('select').not(this).removeProp('disabled');

                $('select option').removeProp('disabled');
                $('select').each(function() {
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    if (val != 'Default' || val != 'Disabled') {
                        $('select option[value="' + val + '"]').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This is a great solution to the scenario.

Comment: If I could follow up with another question, how would I be able to scale it to add rows for Tuesday through Sunday?

Answer (score 0):

All of your js codes must be inside the document.ready() functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //paste your code here....
});
```